# Trying to find a relationship between angular velocity and time derivative of rotation vector

Tags: derivatives, lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations

This question is related to [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187982).

I am trying to simulate IMU measurement of angular velocity $\omega$ without approximation by using discrete steps.

The way I do it is I start from an analytical time varying rotation vector like $\phi(t) = [\sin(at + 1), \sin(bt + 2), \sin(ct + 3)]^T$, whose derivative is easily found to be $\dot{\phi}(t) = [a\cos(at + 1), b\cos(bt + 2), c\cos(ct + 3)]^T$.

Hence, using the Rodrigues formula we can convert $\phi$ to rotation matrix $R$:

$$
R(\phi) = I + \frac{\sin\theta}\theta \phi_\times  + \frac{(1-\cos\theta)}{\theta^2}(\phi_\times)^2,
$$
where $\theta = \|\phi\|$ and $(\cdot)_\times$ denotes the skew-symetric matrix of $(\cdot)$.

We also know that the angular velocity measured in body frame is related to the matrix derivative by

$$
\dot{R} = R\omega_\times \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

Thus, I use Result 1 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0788.pdf) to find an alternative expression for $\dot{R}$, which is:

$$
\dot{R} = \frac{\partial R}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial R}{\partial \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial R}{\partial \phi} \dot{\phi} = -R\dot{\phi}_\times \frac{\phi\phi^T + (R^T-I)\phi_\times}{\|\phi\|^2} \ \ \ \ (2)
$$

So combing (1) and (2) and dropping the common term $R$, we obtain the following

$$
\omega_\times = -\dot{\phi}_\times \frac{\phi\phi^T + (R^T-I)\phi_\times}{\|\phi\|^2}
$$

Here is where the problem appears. On the LHS we have a skew symetric matrix, but on the RHS it is not the case when I plug in some numbers.

Where could I have been wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where does your equation $1$ come from?

Comment: it's the relation ship between rotation matrix derivative and angular velocity (wrt to the body frame). You can check out this reference.

http://www8.tfe.umu.se/courses/elektro/RobotControl/Lecture06_5EL158.pdf